# proper way of using "Matchit" function

Tags: r, propensity-scores, matching

I am trying to use `MatchIT:: matchit` function on my dataset; however, the result I get doesn't seem to be correct; thus, I started wondering if the way I used the function is wrong. the example of the dataset is shown below (it's just a portion of 6000 data I have):

```
         shift age  site  level   length result
         <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <lgl>    
 1           0   3.92     0     3    95 FALSE    
 2           0  10.6      0     3   147 FALSE    
 3           0  13.5      0     4   114 FALSE    
 4           0   0.01     0     2   172 FALSE    
 5           0   4.75     0     4    74 FALSE    
 6           0  17.5      0     5    98 FALSE    
 7           0   2.5      0     4    70 FALSE    
 8           0   2.75     0     3    47 FALSE    
 9           0   5.92     0     3    65 FALSE    
10           0  14.5      0     3   129 FALSE
11           1   2.75     8     4   251 TRUE     
12           1   8.08     8     2   206 TRUE     
13           1   5.42     8     3    95 TRUE     
14           1   4.67     8     2   362 TRUE     
15           1   6.75     8     4   648 TRUE
```

**Data type:** in the above dataset, **shift**, **site**, and **level** are categorical features and **age** and **length** are double.

**what I want to do:** I want to see the effect of **length** on the **result** and see how changing length will affect the result of the test

Since I want to use the nearest method, I thought it's necessary that I create a dummy variable for categorical features as it's necessary for calculating the distance (not sure if it's correct though), so:

```
df_prop_match_dumm <- dummy_cols(df_prop_match, select_columns = c("shift","site","level"))
```

and then I used `matchit` as below:

```
match_out <- matchit(result ~ shift_0 + shift_1 + shift_2 + level_1 + level_2 +
                       level_3 +level_4 +level_5 + site_1 + site_2 +site_3 +site_4 +site_5 +site_6 
                       +site_7 +site_8 + ageyrs ,data = df_prop_match_dumm , method="nearest", ratio=1)
```

is this equation correct? should I include **length** in the `matchit` functions? or it's not necessary as we want to find the effect of length?

please advise how is the proper way to do it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To use matching, you need a binary variable that is the purported cause. You do not have that here. `length` is the purported cause, and it is not binary. You cannot use matching for this type of analysis.

Comment: Thanks Noah. So to clarify more on this, is what you mentioned kind of limitation of the "MatchIt" package or generally for any type of matching we should have a binary purported cause? what do you recommend to do in this case, if I want to see the effect of "length" on "result"?

Comment: To summarize, what I want to do is that for each person in data frame 1 (result==TRUE), I want to find the closest person in data frame 2 (result==FALSE). The features I am looking at for measuring closeness are "shift" "age"  "site"  "level". Then after matching each person from dat frame 1 to data frame 2 I can compare their "length". Previously, I used "fuzzyjoin" to do this; however, now I am looking for more valid algorithm to do this

Comment: This is a limitation of the statistical method, not `MatchIt`. You can just run a logistic regression of `result` on `length` and the other covariates. Is there a reason you didn't want to do this in the first place? This is by far the most common method of modeling the relationship between a continuous predictor and a binary outcome.

Comment: The main reason is that I am looking for finding causality effect rather than correlation. That's why I am trying to find a similar match from group 1 in group 2  and then when I created these groups I can investigate the relationship between average length for group 1 and 2.

Comment: Matching and regression are equally able to estimate causal effects. Matching isn't more causal than regression. Correlation without confounding *is* causation. Both matching and regression have the potential to adjust for confounding if you have measured and correctly included all the relevant confounding variables.

Comment: Thanks, Noah for clarification, so I am going to use regression instead and will hopefully get the proper result